# How to get a facebook profile picture under https?

Tags: facebook, graph, oauth

Is it possible to get an facebook profile picture under https using the new Graph API?

We run a site under https, but the profile picture returned by the facebook Graph API is always served as http (when using https://graph.facebook.com/XXX/picture, the request is redirects to http:// ...).  The result is the dreaded mixed-content message.

Anybody know of a workaround?

Comment: Instead of providing the image link directly to the client you proxy it through your web application. Alternatively you could try to load it using javascript, not sure if that will work but it is worth a try.

Comment: I was trying to avoid proxying it, but in the end, that seemed like the easiest solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Here is the fix:
you need to the parameter: return_ssl_resources=true

example:

https://graph.facebook.com/FB_UID/picture?return_ssl_resources=true

Comment: `return_ssl_resources=true` also works for other API endpoints e.g. /me/videos?return_ssl_resources=true. Or a video object http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2031763147233%3Freturn_ssl_resources%3Dtrue vs http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2031763147233

Answer (score 1):

Use *link 1* to get a high resolution image, *link 2* to get an icon sized image where 'xxxx' refer to 'facebook_user_id'.

- link 1 :
  https://graph.facebook.com/xxxx/picture?type=large
- link 2 :
  https://graph.facebook.com/xxxx/picture?type=small

Answer (score -1):

The Graph API is essentially a very basic API, it's probably not the most efficient method to grab images. A better alternative is to learn how to uSe "FQL" and create a FQL that grabs all the UID's profile pictures. This way, instead of hundred and hundreds of calls, which can be very slow, you grab all the info you need in one call.

Comment: FQL can't return a picture but only a URL to a picture so you have to issue those 'hundreds' of requests anyway. By using graph you actually save one request.