# Facebook https profile picture request resultsi n warning

Tags: facebook

New FB graph API otherwise working great, but when I make a request to a pic the link below calls a http request to get the image picture, resulting in browsers telling me that the page is only partially encryped.  Any quick way around this?

https://graph.facebook.com/NAME/picture

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199164#4403576
The solution is to use https://graph.facebook.com/FB_UID/picture?return_ssl_resources=true